# Why my system doesn't recognize wifi adapter?

Tags: wifi-driver

I have a Ralink Wireless Adapter MT-7601u and under Debian 11 it doesn't show up.I really want to use Debian.In Ubuntu and Linux Mint and also elementary os the wifi adapter it is recognized.

Comment: From [Ralink firmware mt7601u not working on debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/353079/ralink-firmware-mt7601u-not-working-on-debian-id-148f7601) you may need to make sure you have the drivers installed. Seems confirmed that `sudo apt install firmware-misc-nonfree` might fix it by https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/691493/what-is-the-m7601-bin-firmware-in-debian-11

Comment: With this:apt-get install firmware-ralink firmware-misc-nonfree,i get:Package firmware-misc-nonfree is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package firmware-ralink is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'firmware-ralink' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'firmware-misc-nonfree' has no installation candidate

Comment: From the second link "You need to add `contrib` and `non-free` to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` following the second example in [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Example_sources.list)."

Comment: I get the same error...

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/457061/ralink-mt7601u-148f7601-wi-fi-adapter-installation for adding driver. Or buy a USB WiFi dongle, available for US$10 or so, that Debian recognizes.

Comment: Ok.I'll buy a new one.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

With the help of you guys i managed to make it work editing some parts.
What i did is this:

Add backports to your /etc/apt/sources.list :

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free
```

Run :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-cache search linux-image
```

install the latest linux-image ...:

```
sudo apt-get -t bullseye install linux-base
sudo apt-get install linux-image-5.10.0-16-amd64
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-5.10.0-16-amd64
```

Reboot

Run :

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-ralink firmware-misc-nonfree
sudo modprobe mt7601u
```

Reboot